# SSIS WMI query to count errors in applicaiton event log

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I know there is a WMI Data Reader task, but I dont want ALL the error log results, just a count.  Also you cant seem to do COUNT(*) in a WMI query, you have to count your results afterwards?  So, what is a good way to count these results.  I dont want to put them in a table.  I just want the count of the errors from the windows event log for the last 24 hours.

The query Im going use is something like this

"SELECT * FROM Win32_NtLogEvent WHERE Logfile='Application' and Type='error' and TimeWritten > '03/10/2015' "

However, I need to get only the count of these results.  Im thinking this might be better done with a script task?

**[update]**
Along with Kyle's reply below, I found this 
http://nirav.extreme-advice.com/2013/02/22/ssis-package-to-get-disk-space-info-with-wmi-and-script-task/

The above, basically changes how i was approaching things.  Instead of trying to save the results to a single value variable, I changed it to an object type and data table.  Then added a script task to simply grab the count of the datatable and then save that into my variable for the count.

Comment: Is this part of a larger package effort, or is the entire goal of the package just to produce the count of this query?

Comment: Its part of a larger package.  I want to send the output of the wmi query into a variable, which ends up getting written into a table with other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, there are two* ways to achieve this: a Script Task (more direct, but requires scripting) or using the Row Count transformation (using only out-of-the-box SSIS.)

The "no-code" method:

1. Create a WMI Data Reader task. Write your query results to a CSV file.
2. Create a Data Flow Task. Use your flat file as a source. Add a Row Count transformation and write the count to a variable. Push your flat file data to a Recordset variable (it can be ignored.)
3. Log your record count variable however you want (Execute SQL task into database, write to file, send email, etc.)

If you do choose to use scripting, my recommendation is to bypass the overhead of the WMI Data Reader task and do the entire thing in a Script Task.

And depending on the scope of your project you might be better off writing a PowerShell script to get the value and just use an Execute Process task to run the script and either push the value via stdout into SSIS or do the logging directly in the PowerShell script.

Comment: *There are 1,000 ways to do everything in SSIS.